# Extract field name from accessor, or use the accessor to set?

Tags: javascript

I am passing around an accessor function

```
let species_accessor = d => d.species;
```

Given an object

```
let alpha = {};
```

I would like to use whichever field (`'species'` here) the accessor is defined on, to set that field in the object.

```
species_accessor(alpha) = 'unknown';
```

That doesn't fly.

```
console.log(alpha);
```

I could forget about passing around an accessor function and simply pass around the name of the field

```
let species_field_name = 'species';
```

and then it's quite simple to set the field

```
let beta = {};
beta[species_field_name] = 'unknown';
console.log(beta);
```

but that is quite clumsy.

How do I extract from an accessor function the name of the field, or otherwise use the accessor to set rather than to get?

**Update**

One [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61108023/704972) is to define a pair of functions. Can the pair of functions be encoded into one with a variation on the `if (!arguments.length)` trick?

Comment: let species_accessor = d => d.species || 'unknown';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one function to both get and set values, then you can check if a second argument is provided:

```js
function speciesAccessor(obj, val) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        obj.species = val;
    } else {
        return obj.species;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does the trick and fits with a common idiom. Though if you're reading this do note that Bergi (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61108023/704972) is a lone voice reminding us that efficiency matters in JS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that with a getter function. You would need to pass around a complete accessory, i.e. a getter/setter pair:

```
let speciesAccessor = {
    get(o) { return o.species; },
    set(o, v) { o.species = v; },
};
```

Then you can do

```
speciesAccessor.set(alpha, 'unknown');
```

Comment: That makes sense. Rather than flood SO with questions, I updated the question to rule out a simple solution. Could you confirm that there is no easy way out (of either passing a pair of functions, or of passing the name of the field)?

Comment: @Calaf "*Can the pair of functions be encoded into one with a variation on the `if (!arguments.length)` trick?*" - yes, you can just distinguish between calls with one or with two arguments. However, using two functions is more efficient - and I would even suggest you make a `class` for that, with useful functions for composition of field accesses etc… But this all depends on the problem you're trying to solve.